# How to properly throw and handle errors in promises in Sails.js?

Tags: promise, sails.js, q

I'm starting to convert my callback code to promises in Sails.js, but I don't understand how I can raise custom errors and handle them in the promise chain. Sails.js uses Q as its promise library.

```js
User.findOne({email: req.param('professorEmail'), role: 'professor'})
    .then(function (user) {
      if (user) {
        return Course.create({
          user_id: user.id,
          section: req.param('section'),
          session: req.param('session'),
          course_code: req.param('course_code')
        });
      } else {
        // At this point `user` is undefined which means that no professor was found so I want to throw an error.
        // Right now the following statement does throw the error, but it crashes the server.
        throw new Error('That professor does not exist.');
        // I want to be able to handle the error in the .fail() or something similar in the promise chain.
      }
    }).then(function (createSuccess) {
      console.log(createSuccess);
    }).fail(function (err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
```

Right now the `.fail()` is never called because the thrown error crashes the server.

Comment: No that error cannot be crashing the server, any thrown errors inside promises will instantly stop and start execution at the nearest .fail handler

Comment: @Esailija Do you know as a fact if this is how promises behave in Sails.js? Because what you said is what I'm expecting. I tried a simpler scenario where I threw the error right after entering the first `.then()` and it still crashes the server isntead of going to `.fail()`.

Comment: Reading their github page it doesn't appear sails even uses promises. Are you sure your server is not crashing from `.then()` method not even existing?

Comment: @Esailija It's on the Sails.js ORM github page (https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline). The server does not complain about a method not existing. But now that you mention it, I'm going to check the possibility of it being a version issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Waterline's claim](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline#query-methods) `complete Q promise object` after the first `then` seems untrue by your test. I've verified it myself as well and found a workaround.

You can do this :

```js
var Q = require('q');
[...]
Q(User.findOne({email: req.param('professorEmail'), role: 'professor'}))
.then(function (user) {
  if (user) {
    return Course.create({
      user_id: user.id,
      section: req.param('section'),
      session: req.param('session'),
      course_code: req.param('course_code')
    });
  } else {
    // At this point `user` is undefined which means that no professor was found so I want to throw an error.
    // Right now the following statement does throw the error, but it crashes the server.
    throw new Error('That professor does not exist.');
    // I want to be able to handle the error in the .fail() or something similar in the promise chain.
  }
}).then(function (createSuccess) {
  console.log(createSuccess);
}).fail(function (err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

This will return a true Q promise.

Comment: Error: Cannot find module 'q'

Comment: you should `npm install q` beforehand.

Answer (score 9):

Use `.catch()` instead of `.fail()`.