# Create an object from multiple database collections (SailsJS, MongoDB, WaterlineJS)

Tags: mongodb, sails.js

I'm very new to Sails and noSQL databases and I'm having trouble gathering information together from different collections. Basically I need to gather an object of items from one collection and then use a foreign key stored in that collection to add data from a separate collection so the whole thing can be sent as one object.

Currently I find all the items in a collection called Artwork, then I'm using a for loop to iterate through the artworks. I need to use an id stored in Artworks to query a collection called Contacts but having successfully found the contact I am unable to pass it back out of the function to add it to the Artwork object.

```
    find: function ( req, res, next ) {
            Artwork.find().done( function ( err, artwork ) {
                // Error handling
                if (err) {
                    return console.log(err);
                } else {
                    for ( x in artwork ) {
                        var y = artwork[x]['artistID'];
                        // Get the artsists name
                        Contact.find(y).done( function( err, contact ) {
                            // Error handling
                            if ( err ) {
                                return console.log(err);
                            // The Artist was found successfully!
                            } else {
                                var artist = contact[0]['fullName'];
                            }
                        });
                        artwork[x]['artistsName'] = artist;
                    }
                    res.send(artwork);
                }
            });
}
```

The result of the above code is an error thrown that tells me 'artist' is undefined. The variable is not being passed outside the function?

Any advice greatly received.

Answer (score 1):

Sails is about to release an update that will include associations.  In the meantime, here's an answer for how you can accomplish it using async.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/20050821/1262998

Comment: Many thanks @JohnGalt. I look forward to the update: [(github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/124)](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/124). In the meantime I'll have a go with the async option.